# AWK calculate percentages for each input file and output summary to single file

Tags: awk

I have hundreds of csv files with the same format. I want to 'summarise' each file by counting occurrences of the word "Correct" in column 3 and calculating the percentage of "Corrects" per file (i.e. "Correct"s / total number of rows in that file). I am currently doing this for each file with a shell 'for-loop', but this isn't ideal for [reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Minimal reproducible example:

```
cat file1.csv
id,prediction,evaluation
1,high,Correct
2,low,Correct
3,high,Incorrect
4,low,Incorrect

cat file2.csv
id,prediction,evaluation
1,high,Correct
2,low,Correct
3,high,Correct
4,low,Incorrect
```

Correct answer for each individual file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; print "model,total_correct,accuracy"} NR>1{n++; if($3 == "Correct"){correct++}} END{print FILENAME, correct, correct / n}' file1.csv
model,total_correct,accuracy
file1.csv,2,0.5

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; print "model,total_correct,accuracy"} NR>1{n++; if($3 == "Correct"){correct++}} END{print FILENAME, correct, correct / n}' file2.csv
model,total_correct,accuracy
file2.csv,3,0.75
```

My desired outcome:

```
model,total_correct,accuracy
file1.csv,2,0.5
file2.csv,3,0.75
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `awk` you can try following code. Written and tested with shown samples. Using `ENDFILE` here to make life easy. Also added 2 more conditions into the code: 1st: Increasing count for `n` when there is NO NULL line. 2nd: While getting average to make sure no error comes(in case zero records found) it should print N/A rather than an OOTB generated error. I have also changed from `NR>1` to `FNR>1` since NR will be a cumulative count and we need FNR which reset the line number from each Input_file's beginning.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  print "model,total_correct,accuracy"
}
FNR>1{
  if(NF)             { n++       }
  if($3 == "Correct"){ correct++ }
}
ENDFILE{
  printf("%s,%d,%.02f\n",FILENAME, correct, (n>0&&n?(correct / n):"N/A"))
  correct=n=0
}
'  *.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

With the standard awk, you can increment counts in an array indexed by filename and whether the third column is `"Correct"`, and iterate through the filenames in the end to output the statistics:

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";print"model,total_correct,accuracy"}
FNR>1{++r[FILENAME,$3=="Correct"]}
END{
  for(i=1;i<ARGC;++i){
    f=ARGV[i];
    print f,c=r[f,1],c/(r[f,0]+c)
  }
}' *.csv
```